# When to use force_update in Django's save()?

Tags: python, mysql, django

Django [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#forcing-an-insert-or-update) state that:

> In some rare circumstances, it’s necessary to be able to force the save() method to perform an SQL INSERT and not fall back to doing an UPDATE. Or vice-versa: update, if possible, but not insert a new row. In these cases you can pass the force_insert=True or force_update=True parameters to the save() method. Obviously, passing both parameters is an error: you cannot both insert and update at the same time!

What are these **rare circumstances**?

Basically, when should one use `force_update=True`?

Comment: For example when you have to change the PK, which should really be a are circumstance.

Comment: @KlausD. In that case you have to rely on `Queryset.update()`. `Model.save(force_update=True)` would use the new pk to determine which row to update, and fail because no such row exists.